# Problems in if else statements in C

Tags: c, if-statement

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){

int month, day;
printf("Enter the input : ");
scanf("%d %d",&month,&day);

if (day == 1 &&  month==1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4){
    printf("Green\n");
}
else if(day == 2 && month == 5 || month == 6 || month ==7 || month ==8 ){
    printf("Red");
}

return 0;
}
```

In the above code whenever I choose `d = 1` and `month = 1-4` , it is supposed to print green which it does correctly. The problem is when I choose `day = 2 & month = 8 or 7 or 6` it is supposed to print `red` but it is printing `green`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you read this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence ?

Comment: Enclose the months in a paranthesis for clarity. `(day == 1 && (month==1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4))`

Comment: Yeah. I missed the parenthesis. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SparKot not only for clarity but rather for correctness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to check the day and month diffently.
Try this instead:

```
if (day == 1 &&  (month==1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4)){
    printf("Green\n");
}
else if(day == 2 && (month == 5 || month == 6 || month ==7 || month ==8)){
    printf("Red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It just works fine as you expected.
Maybe, you forgot that your first input is `month` and `day` is second.
Try again now.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
int main(){ 
int month, day; 
printf("Enter the input : "); 
scanf("%d %d",&month,&day); 
if ((day == 1 && month==1) || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4)
{ printf("Green\n"); } 
else if(day == 2 && month == 5 || month == 6 || month ==7 || month ==8 ){ 
printf("Red"); } 
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is plain wrong and your code indentation is terrible. You name suggests that you know that indentation is most important in Python. In C it's also important, but not for defining the program structure but for readability

Comment: I just copied his code and paste it here.  Since && has higher precedence than || operator parenthesis doesn't matter. It's just gives a warning not an error. And I believe input is provided reverse is the actual reason for this question.

Comment: Sorry, this answer is wrong, and your code formatting is terrible. The OP has accepted the other answer which is correct. Have a look at it. You probably misunderstood something.

Comment: Yeah, because of you guys. Actually, he accepted my answer earlier. Then he removed since someone talked about indentation and things like you. Unlike you, he removed his comment

Comment: Sorry to insist, but your `if ((day == 1 && month==1) || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4)` does exactly the same as the OP's original code `if (day == 1 &&  month==1 || month == 2 || month == 3 || month ==4)`. Read everything closely again. The other answer has been accepted and upvoted for a good reason

Comment: That's what I told you earlier(copy paste). You can take some time and read his question again. If your inputs are 7 and 2 it returns **Green** while **Red** is returned for 2 and 7. *#Order of the inputs is the actual reason op to confuse**

Comment: While input order does matter, this code still has issues; it will print "Green" if you enter 2 for the day and 4 for the month.  The problem the OP is facing (and has acknowledged) is that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, so the "Green" branch will be taken if `month` is 2, 3, or 4, *regardless of the value of `day`*.  That's clearly not what the OP intends.  Yeah, sure, this code produces the expected output for a specific set of inputs, but it doesn't produce expected outputs for all sets of inputs.

Comment: JohnBode and Jabberwocky, thanks for the clarification. I got this lately. I delete this answer since it's not helpful at all.